# Delay showing button on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, less

I have angular code which shows different time segments for a particular day. I want a delete button to appear over a segment if the cursor hovers over it for 2 seconds. I have tried a few different things but I can't seem to get it working

```css
.delete-button {
    display: none;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}
        
.time-segment:hover .delete-button{
     display: block;
     transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<button class="delete-button">delete</button>
```

Comment: How it will work on mobile device?

Comment: At the minute, this is for non-mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

CSS 'display' property is not animatable. You need to use visibility if you want to do it purely with CSS. Many people set transitions on both opacity and visibility, with the visibility lagging ever-so-slightly behind the opacity, so it neatly fades in and out of view.

Answer (score 1):

here, the delete button must be IN your time segment in order for your css to work. this can be done with pure css, but we must know at least the parent div, else there must be one delete for each segment.

if you have multiple segments and you want to delete a specific on, maybe javascript will be more friendly, with angular it can be pretty simple.

```css
.delete-button {
    opacity : 0.2;
}
        
.time-segment:hover .delete-button{
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity 3s cubic-bezier(1,0,1,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="time-segment">
  hover me
  <button class="delete-button">delete</button>
</div>
```